conditional formatting if empty display " average"
im using google sheets
=IF(ISBLANK(Q2), "Average: " & (T2 + V2) / 2, Q2)
iv got this formula i want in the conditional formatting.
i want to know if the conditional formatting could add average and the result if the cell is empty.
or is conditional formatting only able to change the colour
=IF(ISBLANK(Q2), "Average: " & (T2 + V2) / 2, Q2)

Conditional formatting cannot add text to the cell.  Are the cells in the range in question populated by formulas?  If that is the case, you may be able to add a condition that if the resulting evaluation is blank then the value = "Average".
